# How to connect QTableView to a right-click menu

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

With older syntax we had to use the `QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)"` thingy.

Now with Qt5 around-the-corner the older `QtCore.SIGNAL` syntax is not cool any longer as it becomes absolute.

How to modify the working PyQt4 code posted below to make it compatible with PyQt5 (only concerned about connecting the right-click menu)?

```
class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rcMenu=QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.rcMenu.addAction('My Action')
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.onRightClick)

def onRightClick(self, QPos=None):       
    parent=self.sender()
    pPos=parent.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(5, 20))
    mPos=pPos+QPos

    self.rcMenu.move(mPos)
    self.rcMenu.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

`self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.onRightClick)`

with:

`self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.onRightClick)`

```
class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rcMenu=QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.rcMenu.addAction('My Action')
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.onRightClick)

def onRightClick(self, QPos=None):       
    parent=self.sender()
    pPos=parent.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(5, 20))
    mPos=pPos+QPos

    self.rcMenu.move(mPos)
    self.rcMenu.show()
```